# Spring Integration HTTP Outbound Gateway header not forwarder on a consecutive request

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I'm struggling with the following flow:

```java
.enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction("ocp-apim-subscription-key", m ->
        "xxx"))
.handle(Http.outboundGateway("https://northeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3" +
        ".0/read/analyzeResults/abc")
        .mappedRequestHeaders("ocp-apim-subscription-key")
        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET))
.enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction("ocp-apim-subscription-key", m ->
        "xxx"))
.handle(Http.outboundGateway("https://northeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3" +
        ".0/read/analyzeResults/def")
        .mappedRequestHeaders("ocp-apim-subscription-key")
        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET))
```

The first request is submitted correctly and I get the result, for the second one I get *401 UNAUTHORIZED* which means, the *ocp-apim-subscription-key* is not included. I've tried without the second enrichment step as I thought that the headers won't be cleared but it also didn't change anything.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Do I need to configure the header mapper somehow differently?

Here is the output of the debug which clearly shows that the header is included:

```
17:45:31.468 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler - bean 'ocrDocument.http:outbound-gateway#2' for component 'ocrDocument.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3'; defined in: 'processing.OCRIntegrationFlow'; from source: 'bean method ocrDocument' received message: GenericMessage [payload=<200,[Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", Content-Type:"application/json; charset=utf-8", x-envoy-upstream-service-time:"25", CSP-Billing-Usage:"CognitiveServices.ComputerVision.Transaction=1", Strict-Transport-Security:"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload", x-content-type-options:"nosniff", Date:"Mon, 31 Aug 2020 15:45:31 GMT"]>, headers={Transfer-Encoding=chunked, ocp-apim-subscription-key=xxx, id=11fa4a77-d97a-772b-69b6-059de29ef808, contentType=application/json;charset=utf-8, http_statusCode=200 OK, Date=1598888731000, timestamp=1598888731467}]
```

**UPDATE**
I've recorded a session with wireshark (switched to http instead of https as I couldn't get it to work). It seems that in the second request the subscription-key isn't propagated. For some reason in the second one more headers are included.

First one

[image]

Second one

[image]

Comment: The problem probably with something else. Can you confirm with some wire sniffer (Wireshark, for example) that your header is not transferred the second time?

Comment: Thanks Artem. Please take a look at the wireshark results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I see where is the problem:

```
private HttpEntity<?> createHttpEntityFromPayload(Message<?> message, HttpMethod httpMethod) {
Object payload = message.getPayload();
if (payload instanceof HttpEntity<?>) {
    // payload is already an HttpEntity, just return it as-is
    return (HttpEntity<?>) payload;
}
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = mapHeaders(message);
```

Since you propagate a `ResponseEntity` from the first call to the second one, there is indeed no any headers mapping since we just don't do that logic in the `AbstractHttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` and use the provided `HttpEntity` as is.

We can't make an assumption what you would like to do with that, but since you have provided the whole entity, we just don't mutate it and perform request against it as is.

To fix the problem I suggest to include before second call some simple `.transform((p) -> "")` to avoid some HTTP entity assumption.

And yes, you don't need the second header enricher if the value for the `ocp-apim-subscription-key` is the same.

We probably need to improve docs on the matter and explain how request message is handled in this component. Feel free to raise a GH issue!

Comment: Cool, thanks for the explanation! I've tried yesterday with an additional .handle in between but it didn't help. Let me try it out with .transform.